# Countifs not counting anything for some reason

Tags: excel, count, formula, countif

I trying to create a list as a template for our future projects.

[image]

I named column "S" as TurnAround1, then some other columns as TurnAround2, and so on. The cells in that column are the difference between column P and column L, which are dates. So as seen in the image, column P, shows April 23, minus April 14, which is 9 days as seen in column S.

Now on a separate sheet, I'm counting the total number of cells which shows 7 days or less. So I made this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(TurnAround1,"<=7",TurnAround2,"<=7",TurnAround3,"<=7",TurnAround4,"<=7",TurnAround5,"<=7").
```

However, it always results to 0. I also counted the same columns without the "<=7" criteria, but it's also not counting anything. I tried to remove the formula from that cells and just manually entered 9 days, 7, days, etc, but it's not counting anything.

Please help.

Comment: Multiple criteria in a countifs works as an AND not an OR. You probably need sumproduct and you should use regular column references and get rid of the names.

Comment: You might try `=countifs(TurnAround1:TurnAround5, "<=7")`

Comment: I tried this but this also counts the columns in between TurnAround1 to TurnAround5.

Comment: Then you need sumproduct possibly with mod to shorten it.